# Find Root disk Path with SQL query

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

How do I find Server Root disk name with MS SQL query?

For Ex: `c:\`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DB_NAME(dovs.database_id) DBName,
mf.physical_name PhysicalFileLocation,
dovs.logical_volume_name AS LogicalName,
dovs.volume_mount_point AS Drive,
CONVERT(INT,dovs.available_bytes/1048576.0) AS FreeSpaceInMB
FROM sys.master_files mf
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.FILE_ID) dovs
ORDER BY FreeSpaceInMB ASC
GO
```

It will give you the DBname, Physical file location, Logicaldiskname,Drive,FreeSpace. I use this query.

Comment: @MetinAtalay, glad i could help you. Consider Upvote